# How to use anchor tag as submit button in asp.net razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a handler method in razor page with name `OnGetExpense(UsePayload payload)`

page.cshtml:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Filters.From" value="@Model.Filters.From.ToYYYYMMDD()" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Filters.To" value="@Model.Filters.To.ToYYYYMMDD()" />
<a asp-page-handler="Expense" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="border-color: inherit">
Expense
</a>
```

page.cshtml.cs:

```
public IActionResult OnGetExpense(UserPayload filter)
{
    Console.WriteLine(filter.From);
    Console.WriteLine(filter.To);
    return Page();
}
```

The `From` date and to date I am getting is `01-01-0001` it is not submitting the payload I needed.

Is there any tag attribute I can sen the payload with anchor tag?

Please help

Comment: Could you share your UserPayload model ?

Answer (score 1):

Your rendered A tag will create a GET request to the endpoint, you need to to a POST to send the data in the body of the request and for the Controller to bind the Request Body to your UserPayload object.

To send the POST request you can either write some JavaScript and POST to JSON to the end point or wrap the code in a Form.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/4-working-with-forms

Your controller will need to have `HttpPost` attribute assigned.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult OnGetExpense(UserPayload filter)
{
    Console.WriteLine(filter.From);
    Console.WriteLine(filter.To);
    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any tag attribute I can sen the payload with anchor tag?

You can use `asp-route-{value}`

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

cshtml:

```
 <a  asp-page-handler="Expense" asp-route-attendeeid="12" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="border-color: inherit">Expense</a>
```

cshtml.cs

```
 public IActionResult OnGetExpense(int attendeeId)
        {
            return Page();
        }
```

result:

[image]